# Hibernate one to many mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping, one-to-many

I have two tables:

```
<class name="Content" table="language_content" lazy="false">
    <composite-id>  
        <key-property name="contentID" column="contentID"/>  
        <key-property name="languageID" column="languageID"/>           
    </composite-id> 
    <property name="Content" column="Content" />
</class>
```

and

```
<class name="SecretQuestion" table="secretquestions" lazy="true">
    <id name="questionID" type="integer" column="QuestionID">
        <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="question" column="Question"/>
    <property name="isUsing" column="IsUsing"/>
    <bag name="contents" inverse="true" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
        <key column="question" />
        <one-to-many class="Content" />
    </bag>
</class>
```

I'm trying to map the **"question" property** of SecretQuestion to the **"contentID" property** of Content but Eclipse throwing out an exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection: [com.sms.model.entity.SecretQuestion.contents#1]
```

If I replace the `<key column="question" />` with `<key column="contentID" />`, it can run but mapping the wrong data (actually, as far as I see, it maps the questionID with the contentID of Content)

Anyone know how to do what I'm trying to achieve here?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Okey, after modifying as Pascal said, here is the new error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKB65C9692FCD05581:language_content [contentID,languageID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (secretquestions [QuestionID])
```

This error means I have to have a composite primary key for secretquestions table which I don't want :(

**UPDATE**

I will give an example to clearer what I trying to do:

```
Table SecretQuestion
questionID* question answer
1           4        a
2           5        a
3           6        a

Table Content
contentID* languageID* content
1          1           a
1          2           b
2          1           c
2          2           d
3          1           e
3          2           f
4          1           g
4          2           h
5          1           i
5          2           j
6          1           k
6          2           l
```

**Now I want to map question 4, 5, 6 to content ID 4, 5, 6.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this approach cannot work and is not supported by Hibernate (the Content table have composite primary key while I want to mapping it to only one field in the Question table), thus I use a workaround that I only map the question to the contentID and I use a ContentGetter class that will get the content depend on the languageID.